# How to fix attribute validation errors in Coldfusion cfcontent (java.string.lang not supported variable type)?

Tags: java, coldfusion, error-handling, gzip, binary-data

I have a Coldfusion application in which I'm generating HTML server side, compress, manually gzip and send back as a cfcontent.

Looks like this:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="renderedResults">
    <cfoutput><p>Hello World</p></cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfscript>
    compressedHTML = reReplace(renderedResults, "\>\s+\<", "> <", "ALL");
    compressedHTML = reReplace(compressedHTML, "\s{2,}", chr(13), "ALL");
    compressedHTML = reReplace(compressedHTML, "\s{2,}", chr(09), "ALL");
</cfscript>

<cfif cgi.HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING contains "gzip">
    <cfinvoke component="services.utils" method="gzip" stringToZip="#compressedHTML#" returnvariable="compressedHTML"></cfinvoke>   
    <cfheader name="Content-Encoding" value="gzip">
</cfif>

<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<cfheader name="Content-Length" value="#len(compressedHTML)#" >
<cfcontent reset="no" variable="#compressedHTML#" />
<cfreturn  />
```

My GZIP utility function:

```
<cfscript>
    var result="";
    var text=createObject("java","java.lang.String").init(arguments[1]);
    var dataStream=createObject("java","java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream").init();
    var compressDataStream=createObject("java","java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream").init(dataStream);
    compressDataStream.write(text.getBytes());
    compressDataStream.finish();
    compressDataStream.close();

    if(arrayLen(arguments) gt 1){
        result=binaryEncode(dataStream.toByteArray(),arguments[2]);
    }else{
        result=dataStream.toByteArray();
    }
    return result;
</cfscript>
```

I'm running this on all pages and it works well most of the time, no matter if the page is requested straight or via AJAX.

**However sometimes I get the following error**:

`Diagnose: Attribute validation error for tag cfcontent. java.lang.String is not a supported variable type. The variable is expected to contain binary data. <br>The error occurred on line 338.`
`Browser: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)`

which is the `cfcontent` line.

**Question**:
Could this be that a page was requested by browser not supporting GZIP or with GZIP disabled? Because then the HTML would only be compressed and not binary encoded?

If so, would a fix be that I would have to binary encode the compressed HTML?

If both are wrong, please shed some light if you can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting your variable to binary before passing it to cfcontent using the [ToBinary()](http://www.cfquickdocs.com/#ToBinary) function, like this...

```
<cfcontent reset="no" variable="#ToBinary(compressedHTML)#" />
```

Comment: So I guess I would have to check whether I gzipped (already encoded) and if not, use your snippet. Sounds good. If only I could reproduce my error when I need...